# Apple said we can use iMovie to make App Previews, but I can't export the correct size using iMovie

Tags: macos, iphone, imovie

I'm trying to create an App Preview for an iPhone app.

I recorded a screen capture of the app in the native resolution of the phone.

Then I imported the video in iMovie and used iMovie to add transitions and text, and to arrange the clips.

According to Apple, App Previews should be 640x1136 for the iPhone 5 portrait size, but the export menu doesn't support this size or any custom sizes.

Apple said we could use iMovie, but this doesn't seem to work. How can I change the export size?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Make sure you go to File->New App Preview (available on iMovie 10.0.6 on Yosemite).

[image: New App Preview]

Comment: additionally i think the supported export size is always the same of the first video file added to the project. so if you add screen recorded iphone5 footage you will end up with 640x1136

Comment: Make sure you start clean. I copied and paste the edit from the movie format and I still get 1920 x 1080. But if you edit new straight from App Preview format it will be 900 x 1200.

Comment: Tried to down-vote. This does NOT solve the problem. iMovie is broken and WILL NOT export at the right resolution, no matter if you select "New App Preview" or not. Apple, once again, makes absolutely no sense and seems to have no clue how to develop software besides their OS.

Warning: Just. Use. Something. Else.  Just wasted 2 hours. It will only export at the resolution of the first video you import into the project.

Comment: Yeah, even making an app preview on iMovie exports the wrong dimension video

Comment: This is NOT the right answer and needs to be changed. Paul has the correct answer. Apple is idiotic and you have to place an image at the correct dimensions at the beginning (before anything else), then add your video and it will export it at the correct size. It's a hack, but it works.

Answer (score 24):

Add an image to the beginning of the video, e.g. one second splash screen or 0.1 second black/white screen. Make sure the image dimensions match the intended device dimensions. Video added after the image will conform to these dimensions - you will have a resizer option in the preview video to change your video size to match the initial screen dimensions.

You can also remove the beginning image after all of this and your movie will retain the new size.

Comment: What I did was created a new App Preview project, first added a screenshot which is of the correct dimensions and then added the video exported from the other project (this was intended to be a quick fix).

Comment: For those who are a little slow like me... start a new App Preview project and make the first thing you drop into the video the blank screen at preview resolution. It won't work if you try to add it after the fact. Thanks Paul!

Answer (score 8):

If like me and the OP you did all of the work to create your preview only to find that you can't 'share' it as a preview because you did not start it as a preview then here is the answer.

Start a 'New App Preview' then open your original project -> click in the timeline and select all (cmd + a) -> copy that (cmd + C) -> go to your empty app preview -> click in the timeline and -> paste (cmd + V).

All your hard work is now in the app preview video.

Comment: This was a huge help, exactly what I was hoping for.  I guess there is no way to 'convert' a project to App Preview.

Answer (score 4):

It may be possible to use some other software to crop and re-encode the output, but that would be a messy and troublesome process.

Instead, the solution I came to is this:

1. Download a [trial](http://www.apple.com/final-cut-pro/trial/) of Final Cut Pro from Apple.
2. Export your movie to Final Cut Pro using these [instructions](http://help.apple.com/imovie/mac/10.0/#movcbf7e2a3f).

I had some trouble on this step (the menu option was grayed out, initially), but eventually resolved it by making sure all the clips were consolidated in the library.

3. In Final Cut Pro, modify the project settings to use the custom resolution:
   [image: info tab when your project is selected]
4. Follow Apple's instructions for [exporting App Previews with Final Cut Pro](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/final-cut-pro/).

I believe Apple made a mistake in recommending iMovie during WWDC. Actually, on the new [App Preview documentation](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/), they no longer mention iMovie. Perhaps some day they will update iMovie and add support for other export presets.

In the meantime, I would suggest either buying a Final Cut Pro license or using video editing software other than iMovie.

Comment: iMovie ON YOSEMITE certainly has the ability to create app previews and they cover that in detail in https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/imovie/Creating-App-Previews-with-iMovie.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to do it for **low cost and really fast**.

1. Record just one demo from the iPhone 6 plus.
2. Edit it in iMovie as an App Preview project.
3. Export it as a ProRes file

You now have your high quality master from which you will produce all other formats, without having to record more demos on other devices and edit them all over again, which is horribly time consuming.

On the Apple Store buy and download **QuickTime 7 PRO** for just 30 dollars.  This is the seventh marvel in the video world and a very well kept secret: it's cheap and will convert to almost any format! Pro guys know this and use it all the time.

1. Open your master in QT 7 Pro.
2. Select "export as..." Set it to MPEG-4 Video and press the "Options..." button.
3. Use Apple's "[App Preview Specifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html)" to setup the export parameters. The trick when you export to the iPad Format is to check the "Preserve proportions via Letterbox" option". This will add black bars on each side of your iPhone 6+ videos.

Use your freed up time to make your app better!

Comment: I think this is an advertisement for QuickTime, considering it is (as demonstrated by the first answer) completely unnecessary in order to produce the desired result (and doesn't even change the final result in any way, significant or otherwise).

Comment: I thinks it's a valid recommendation. I've use QT-7 Pro for many years. It was perfect for assembling my preview without dealing with the "nuances" of iMovie.

Answer (score 3):

**For exporting:**

Once you have created an App Preview project in iMovie ([see kokernutz's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/153547/60126)) and finished your movie, you can export from the share menu as shown in this screenshot:

[image: App Preview Share Menu]

For some reason the app preview option only showed up when my focus was on the timeline (in other words, if you don't see it, click somewhere on the timeline for your project first).  You can obviously still use the File export to get the same results if you know the right settings (discussed in some of the other answers).

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same surprise. Here's a really easy solution:

From within iMovie:

1. Select Share from menu bar
2. Choose 'Export using Quicktime'

On 'Save Exported File as…' screen:

1. Select 'OPTIONS' (which is toward the bottom of window beside 'Export: Movie to Quicktime')

On 'Movie Settings' window:

1. Select Video Settings button
2. Be sure compression type = H.264
3. Change Frame Rate to = 30 fps
4. Make Compressor Quality = Best
5. Press OK to confirm

Back on 'Movie Settings window:

1. Select 'Size' button under Video section
2. On 'Export Size Settings' screen now
3. Select 'Dimensions' drop down
4. Scroll to bottom and choose 'CUSTOM'
5. You'll now have the option to input: 640 x 1136 (for iPhone 5 series dimensions)
6. Press OK, OK, then Save

Comment: This does not work on the new iMovie. There is no export using Quicktime

Comment: Can you clarify the version of iMovie where this works?

Comment: Apple denied our App Preview submitted with these dimensions.Instead requested the following dimensions: 750 x 1334 So follow the previous protocol for exporting a video from within iMovie, using Quicktime, but make your custom dimensions: 750 x 1334

Answer (score 1):

iMovie is able to export app previews. I just went through the process.

One downside to using iMovie for making an app preview is that the selection of titles is much more limited than in a regular movie.

In a couple weeks I will find out whether Apple accepts my preview.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/imovie/Creating-App-Previews-with-iMovie.pdf

Update: Apple accepted the iMovie-generated app preview.

Comment: How did you get the required 1334x750 size?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using iMovie 10.0.6 on Yosemite. With this version there is an option "New App Preview" under the File menu. Just click on that to start creating your app preview.

As Josh Adams mentioned there are less title options but they are specific for app previews which is handy.

I created my app preview and when clicking on the Share button, there is a new icon "App Preview" which will export the file in the required format. I was able to upload the file to iTunes Connect.

Comment: How did you get the required 1334x750 size?

Comment: The app preview clip I generated had resolution of 1080x1920 and was accepted in iTunesConnect.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this for my App Preview created with iMovie. The solution is simple but iMovie does not make it obvious.

All you need to do is at the very beginning of your movie, add a static image that is the correct resolution that Apple is asking for. [Here's a reference to those resolution requirements from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/writerid/itc_videopreview_screenshots).

This will mean creating separate videos for each phone size. Fortunately, across all products there are only 3 screen resolutions (6 total for Portrait & Landscape).

To do this:

1. Open iMove
2. Select **File > New App Preview**
3. Add the static image for your **first phone size**
4. Complete making your video
5. Make a second video by selecting **File > New App Preview**
6. Add the static image for your **second phone size**
7. Go back to your first video, select all elements of the video (*except the first static image*) and **COPY**
8. Go to your second video, and **PASTE** all of those elements after the static image

That's it! You can check that the video is being created at the correct resolution by clicking the "Settings" button to the top right of the Video Timeline. There is should give you a tooltip and at the top say "App Preview - [*YOUR VIDEO RESOLUTION*]"

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I hit this problem in mojave 10.14.2 on macbook pro.
I wanted to make macOS Previews of size 1920x1080.
Tried to record the macbook screen, but after sharing the video, I ended up with 1136x640 dimensions.

The solution was "simple". I plugged in an external display with 1920x1080 resolution and made the screen recording on that display.

1. Record the video on a display with 1920x1080 resolution.
2. in iMovie create a new "App Preview" project
3. add the video and edit it if required (make sure you has an audio channel)
4. share it as App Preview

The resulting video has the right format for the Mac App Store

Answer (score 0):

iMovie as of today (Jan 2015) only lets you create an app preview export at 1920 x 1080, which while great for the iPhone 6+ is useless for creating all the other sizes and aspect ratios needed. I had to bite the bullet and buy FCPX, this allowed me to export at all the resolutions and easily mod the aspect ratio's of the imported raw video.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick using just iMovie and Quicktime to get the right dimensions.

1. Use QuickTime to record a short clip from the size of the device you need
2. Use iMovie and insert that clip into a new "App Preview" project
3. Add your actual video after the short clip

Now, any clips that you export will be in the right dimensions.

If you need to hide your short clip, you can shorten it to 0.1 seconds. Put a title over it and delete the text. Now your video starts with 0.1 seconds of a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

**Sometimes the "Video in wrong format" error has nothing to do with your video or format.**  It's THEIR server.

I had a video that uploaded fine one day and got the ERROR : "Your app video preview is in the wrong format."  I did everything I could to tweak, check, change, re-export etc etc to fix it - thinking that it was me.  It wasn't.

They have server issues and give an error when there's nothing wrong on your end.

**HOW IT WORKED FOR ME**

- Logout of iTunes Connect
- Relax
- Go to sleep
- Wake up in the morning, relogin to iTC and try again. IT WORKS!  With the exact same video file in the exact same format!!!

My steps were to upload the new video.  Once I see the play button in Safari, I played the video all the way through.  Closed that popup.  Save.  Then submit.  I did get that message that says it could take 24 hrs for video to process but I did not get the format error.

Good luck.  Hope this helps someone.